# Assembly language of objective c with block

Tags: assembly, objective-c-blocks

I want to know how the assembly language of the block in Objective-C.
And I have written a demo of the Objective-C:

```
-(void)testFunction:(id) arg1 completeBlock:(TestBlock)block {
    NSLog(@"123");

    block([[PYIDEHelper alloc] init], 100, 234.5);
}
```

And the TestBlock definition is :

```
typedef void (^TestBlock) (PYIDEHelper* helper, int i, float f);
```

And the assembly what I got is :

```
`-[NSObject(Xcode_Plugin_Template_Extension) testFunction:completeBlock:]:
0x10f5361d0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
0x10f5361d1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x10f5361d4 <+4>:   subq   $0x50, %rsp
0x10f5361d8 <+8>:   leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax
0x10f5361dc <+12>:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)           
0x10f5361e0 <+16>:  movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x10f5361e4 <+20>:  movq   $0x0, -0x18(%rbp)
0x10f5361ec <+28>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f5361ef <+31>:  movq   %rdx, %rsi
0x10f5361f2 <+34>:  movq   %rcx, -0x28(%rbp)
0x10f5361f6 <+38>:  callq  0x10f536312               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
0x10f5361fb <+43>:  leaq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
0x10f5361ff <+47>:  movq   $0x0, -0x20(%rbp)
0x10f536207 <+55>:  movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rcx
0x10f53620b <+59>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f53620e <+62>:  movq   %rcx, %rsi
0x10f536211 <+65>:  callq  0x10f536312               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
0x10f536216 <+70>:  leaq   0x12d3(%rip), %rax        ; @"123"
0x10f53621d <+77>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f536220 <+80>:  movb   $0x0, %al
0x10f536222 <+82>:  callq  0x10f5362b8               ; symbol stub for: NSLog
0x10f536227 <+87>:  movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rcx
0x10f53622b <+91>:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x10f53622e <+94>:  movq   0x1b3b(%rip), %rsi        ; (void *)0x000000010f537e30: PYIDEHelper
0x10f536235 <+101>: movq   0x1a34(%rip), %rdi        ; "alloc"
0x10f53623c <+108>: movq   %rdi, -0x30(%rbp)
0x10f536240 <+112>: movq   %rsi, %rdi
0x10f536243 <+115>: movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi
0x10f536247 <+119>: movq   %rcx, -0x38(%rbp)
0x10f53624b <+123>: movq   %rdx, -0x40(%rbp)
0x10f53624f <+127>: callq  0x10f5362e8               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10f536254 <+132>: movq   0x19ad(%rip), %rsi        ; "init"
0x10f53625b <+139>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f53625e <+142>: callq  0x10f5362e8               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x10f536263 <+147>: movl   $0x64, %edx               
0x10f536268 <+152>: movss  0xc8c(%rip), %xmm0
0x10f536270 <+160>: movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdi
0x10f536274 <+164>: movq   %rax, %rsi
0x10f536277 <+167>: movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rcx
0x10f53627b <+171>: movq   %rax, -0x48(%rbp)
0x10f53627f <+175>: callq  *0x10(%rcx)
0x10f536282 <+178>: movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax
0x10f536286 <+182>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f536289 <+185>: callq  0x10f5362f4               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
0x10f53628e <+190>: xorl   %edx, %edx
0x10f536290 <+192>: movl   %edx, %esi
0x10f536292 <+194>: leaq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax
0x10f536296 <+198>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x10f536299 <+201>: callq  0x10f536312               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
0x10f53629e <+206>: leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x10f5362a2 <+210>: xorl   %edx, %edx
0x10f5362a4 <+212>: movl   %edx, %esi
0x10f5362a6 <+214>: callq  0x10f536312               ; symbol stub for: objc_storeStrong
0x10f5362ab <+219>: addq   $0x50, %rsp
0x10f5362af <+223>: popq   %rbp
0x10f5362b0 <+224>: retq
```

I can understand before this line:

```
0x10f536263 <+147>: movl   $0x64, %edx
```

And I don't know how to explain the content of the assembly after this line.

Has someone understand disassembling the assembly of the Objective-C?
Please help me.

Comment: It looks like you compiled with `-O0`, so gcc does a lot of redundant loads/stores.  `-Og` output is much more readable.  `-O3` output is sometimes a lot more compact, and the only thing worth looking at if you want to know "what the compiler will do" with real code.  Other than that, is there anything specifically hard to understand?  Look at the x86 tag wiki for docs that explain what each instruction does.  If you're wondering why gcc chose the insns it did, then IDK because I don't know Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for a lot. The assembly is compiled by the Xcode and I don't know how to compile with other arguments. I just want to know how the block work in the assembly. Thanks again.

Comment: Xcode uses clang/LLVM, right?  It has the same settings as gcc, but doesn't support `-Og`.  Its `-O0` output is similarly bloated and braindead.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are familiar with the *System V ABI x86-64* used by your system, if not, for a quick glide take a look [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/System_V_ABI#x86-64) and for a full description look [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi-0.99.7.pdf).

The quote I feel to point out is this

> %xmm0–%xmm1 used to pass and return floating point arguments

Before reading the code I also advice [reading how blocks are implemented](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html) and how [ARC is implemented](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

A quick, and dirty, explanation of blocks is the following:
<sub><sup>*Block are implemented as Obj-C objects. Capture variables are, by default, a `const` copy. If the `__block` modifier is used to let the block change the captured var, the var is than created in the heap instead of using the stack.*</sup></sub>

A quick, limited, and dirty, explanation of ARC is:
<sub><sup>*The compiler use `objc_storeStrong(a, b)` to increment the reference count of b, copy the reference to a, assign b to a and then release a.*</sup></sub>

---

Here the reverse engineering of your code

```
;=== Prolog ===

;This function is called with
;rdi = isa pointer (self)
;rsi = selector (_cmd)
;rdx = arg1 pointer
;rcx = block pointer

pushq  %rbp                   
movq   %rsp, %rbp

subq   $0x50, %rsp      ;Allocate 80 bytes of local storage
                        ;48h bytes out of 50h are used, the remaining are
                        ;for keeping the stack aligned

;Addr        Purpose              Name given by me
;---------|---------------------|-----------------
;rbp-08h     isa pointer          self
;rbp-10h     own selector         _cmd
;rbp-18h     arg1 (retained)      l_arg1
;rbp-20h     block (retained)     l_block 
;rbp-28h     hold copy of block   t_block
;rbp-30h     alloc selector       s_alloc
;rbp-38h     hold copy of block   t_block2
;rbp-40h     hold copy of block   t_block3
;rbp-48h     PYIDEHelper obj      helper_obj

;As you can see, some of this variables are rubbish generated by the
;compiler
;I made this table during the reverse engineering

;=== ARC housekeeping ===

leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax        ;rax = rbp-18h = &l_arg1

movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)         ;Save isa pointer into self       
movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)        ;Save own selector  into _cmd
movq   $0x0, -0x18(%rbp)        ;Set l_arg1 to nil
movq   %rax, %rdi               ;rdi = &l_arg1
movq   %rdx, %rsi               ;rsi = arg1 pointer

movq   %rcx, -0x28(%rbp)        ;Save block pointer into t_block

callq  0x10f536312              ;objc_storeStrong(&l_arg1, arg1)

;l_arg1 is a pointer to arg1 object, now retained


leaq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax        ;rax = &l_block

movq   $0x0, -0x20(%rbp)        ;Set l_block to nil
movq   -0x28(%rbp), %rcx        ;Useless temporary move of t_block into rcx
movq   %rax, %rdi               ;rdi = &l_block
movq   %rcx, %rsi               ;rsi = t_block

callq  0x10f536312              ;objc_storeStrong(&l_block, tblock)

;l_block is a pointer to block, now retained

;=== Body ===

;Log
leaq   0x12d3(%rip), %rax       ;rax = addr @"123"
movq   %rax, %rdi               ;rdi = addr @"123"
movb   $0x0, %al                ;No more varargs in vector regs
callq  0x10f5362b8              ;NSLog(@"123");


movq   -0x20(%rbp), %rcx        ;rcx = l_block
movq   %rcx, %rdx               ;rdx = l_block

movq   0x1b3b(%rip), %rsi       ;Class PYIDEHelper (it a isa ptr)
movq   0x1a34(%rip), %rdi       ;"alloc" selector

movq   %rdi, -0x30(%rbp)        ;Save "alloc" selector into s_alloc
movq   %rsi, %rdi               ;rdi = Class PYIDEHelper
movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rsi        ;rsi = s_alloc

movq   %rcx, -0x38(%rbp)        ;t_block2 = l_block
movq   %rdx, -0x40(%rbp)        ;t_block3 = l_block
callq  0x10f5362e8              ;objc_msgSend(Class PYIDEHelper, "alloc")

;Call [PYIDEHelper alloc] and return address of allocated obj in rax
;RAX = PYIDEHelper obj

movq   0x19ad(%rip), %rsi       ;"init" selector
movq   %rax, %rdi               ;rdi = PYIDEHelper obj
callq  0x10f5362e8              ;objc_msgSend(PYIDEHelper obj, "init")

;Call [obj init] and return new address (if changed) in rax 
;RAX = PYIDEHelper obj (initd)


;Call to block

movl   $0x64, %edx          ;rdx = 100 (sign extended)           
movss  0xc8c(%rip), %xmm0   ;xmm0 = 234.5f
                            ;movss is mov scalar single precision 

;These are the numeric parameters, the float one is loaded from memory

movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdi    ;rdi = l_block
movq   %rax, %rsi           ;rsi = PYIDEHelper obj
movq   -0x38(%rbp), %rcx    ;rcx = l_block
movq   %rax, -0x48(%rbp)    ;Save PYIDEHelper obj  into helper_obj
callq  *0x10(%rcx)          ;call block->invoke(l_block, helper_obj, 100, 234.5f)

;A block is an object, the first field is the isa pointer (8 bytes)
;then there is a flags field (4 byte) and a reserved field (4 byte).
;At the 16th bytes (10h) there is the invoke function pointer
;See the link on block implementation for the struct layout

;=== ARC Housekeeping ===

movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rax    ;rax = helper_obj
movq   %rax, %rdi           ;rdi = helper_obj
callq  0x10f5362f4          ;objc_release(helper_obj)


xorl   %edx, %edx           ;rdx = 0 (zero extended)
movl   %edx, %esi           ;rsi = 0 (sign extended)
leaq   -0x20(%rbp), %rax    ;rax = &l_block
movq   %rax, %rdi           ;rdi = &l_block
callq  0x10f536312          ;objc_storeStrong(&l_block, 0)

;This set the local pointer to l_block to nil and release it

leaq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi    ;rdi = &l_arg1
xorl   %edx, %edx           ;rdx = 0 (zero extended)
movl   %edx, %esi           ;rsi = 0 (sign extended)
callq  0x10f536312          ;objc_storeStrong(&l_arg1, 0);

;This set the local pointer to l_arg1 to nil and release it

;=== Prolog ===

addq   $0x50, %rsp          ;Free space

popq   %rbp                 ;Restore caller frame pointer
retq                        ;Return
```

Comment: Thanks, you save me! But I still have some questions:1.The table (with this 'Name given by me' header.) of the stack is according to the content below, right?2.

Comment: @PlutoY, yes I made it while reverse engineering. I made the names up based on the use of the corresponding stack location.

Comment: Thanks, you save me! But I still have some questions:1.The table (with this 'Name given by me' header.) of the stack is according to the below contents below, right?  2. I didn't see the content which had been put in -0x20(%rbp), and then how do I know the content of -0x20(%rbp) is the block? 3. According to this line(`movq   $0x0, -0x20(%rbp)        ;Set l_block to nil`), the content of  -0x20(%rbp) has been set to nil, Why does the instructions below still can get the block point from  -0x20(%rbp)?Thanks again.

Comment: @PlutoY becouse of what `objc_storeStrong` does. It writes in `-0x20(%rbp)` a reference to the parameter `block` (which is given to it as its second argument).

Comment: @PlutoY You are welcome :) If you think I should make the answer clearer, just tell me.

Comment: Your description is not quite correct. Global blocks are for blocks that don't capture variables (and so there is no state and there is just a single global copy -- i.e. a singleton). Blocks that capture variables start out as stack blocks, and then when they are copied they get copied into malloc blocks.

Comment: @newacct Woops, you are right. Thanks! Mind if I copy your comment?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: I guess. You can use the actual class names like `NSMallocBlock` etc.